# Simple JQUERY data retrieving not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with nodeJS 6, jQuery and JSDOM. 
These simple lines of code don't display a thing in the console, whereas they should :

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var doc = jsdom();
var window = doc.defaultView;
var $ = require('jquery')(window);

$.get('http://racknet.noip.me/a.php', function( data, status ) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log("anything");
        });
```

This means the callback function isn't trigerred. Why that ?

Comment: `http://racknet.noip.me/a.php` works fine ?

Comment: What about `http.get` ?

Comment: @Varun Yeah, the address works fine, it's a webpage from my site that just displays "a" and nothing else.

Comment: @Rayon I need to use jQuery wizardry since later I'll need to send data along with the query. Right now it's not the case, because even a simple thing as that is not working.

Comment: If you are requesting the data from another domain, make sure the Access-Control-Allow-Origin & CORS headers are set accordingly.

Comment: @Greg01re What do you mean ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: From what URL are you requesting that page?

Comment: But I thought the "status" var in the query was supposed to show me this kind of errors. You mean that if the server refuses the connection, the query simply get lost instead of triggering the function that could display the error ?

Comment: The server refuse the request and thus doesn't answer, so we could say the query is lost indeed. The status variable will only show you the status code the server responded with. Eg 404 if it didn't find the url, 401 unauthorized etc.

Comment: the Option response is received from the server. But the actual request is never sent.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes throws the following error

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://racknet.noip.me/a.php. 
  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Basically you are not allowed to access the api, that's why it's not triggered. BTW, you could use `node-fetch` module instead of importing jquery

EDIT: If you're working with express, this should do the trick:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        next();
    });
```

Comment: I highly doubt a file ending with `php` would be nodeJS file. Just sayin'

Comment: `I'm working with nodeJS 6, jQuery and JSDOM`, quote by OP

Answer (score 0):

Your `a.php` should look like:

```
 <?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
   //. .. your code now
```